# Spring Data JPA - SQL Grammar exception when trying to use IN clause with UPDATE Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update the entities in a certain list using Spring Data JPA. However, I'm getting SQL Grammar Exception.

This is the method:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Call c set c.locationLocked = false, c.locationLockedBy = null, c.locationLockedOn = null WHERE c.callIdentifier IN :timedOutLockedCallsIdentifiers AND c.audit.retired = false")
int expireTimedOutLockedCalls(@Param("timedOutLockedCallsIdentifiers") List<String> timedOutLockedCallsIdentifiers);
```

And this is the root cause:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
```

Comment: you are passing null in query.

timedOutLockedCallsIdentifiers is null while executing query.

Comment: `UPDATE Call c set c.locationLocked = false, c.locationLockedBy = null, c.locationLockedOn = null WHERE c.callIdentifier IN (:timedOutLockedCallsIdentifiers) AND c.audit.retired = false`

Comment: @RaheelaAslam No. I'm not. It's sometimes an empty list, but not null.

Comment: @SangramBadi I've tried both versions before asking and got the same exception.

Comment: yes in IN clause you can not send an empty list and null.

Comment: @RaheelaAslam Thank You. Can you post that as an answer so that I can accept it and give you proper credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing null or empty list in `IN` clause of the query.

Please check `timedOutLockedCallsIdentifiers` before calling above query.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to do it more programatically then in a query

In your repository have the following

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Call c WHERE c.callIdentifier IN :timedOutLockedCallsIdentifiers AND c.audit.retired = :retired")
List<Call> findByCallIdentifiers(List<String> timedOutLockedCallsIdentifiers, Boolean retired)
```

Then in your class

```
List<Call> updated = callRepo.findByCallIdentifiers(identifiers, false)
for(Call c : updated) {
   c.setLocationLocked(false);
   c.setLocationLockedBy(null);
   c.setLocationLockedOn(null); 
}

callRepo.saveAll(updated);
```

This will call the proper underlying updates as needed and cant let spring handle the query syntax properly

Comment: I don't want to retrieve all the eagerly fetched attributes in the Call object in this special case.

Comment: Fetch type is lazy by default unless you're specifically setting it to eager in which  you might want to reconsider. It is best practice to keep everything at lazy (for performance) and then write spring methods queries for eager fetch by using `left join fetch`

Comment: Fetch type is not lazy by default in ManyToOne and OneToOne relationships as per the JPA specs. They were lazy by default previously in Hibernate but this was changed to honor the standard. I do agree that this is the best practice with one caveat: when you know that some attributes will always be needed when you need the object, which is my current case.

Comment: Fair enough, i was thinking more along the lines of one-to-many but you're right about many-to-one and one-to-one.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer because it's a perfectly valid solution. Thanks for taking the time to help.